# Create all Entity Class Tables automatically on each new X-TenantID in Multi-Tenancy

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase, multi-tenant

We are developing an application with separate schema based multi tenancy with PostgreSQL and Spring Boot. I am sending the `X-TenantID` header in each server request as a Schema name. However, I am able to create a new schema as `tenantId` on my request but I am unable to create all Entity classes automatically in that new schema. Auto tables are only created in public schema only.  Due to this I am always getting `NO Table Found Exception in hibernate`. What I want that on each new schema tables get created automatically on new request.
Please provide me the solution for my query.

Comment: how are you creating the tables at the moment?

Comment: @bilak At the moment on application startup,  `jpa.hhibernate.ddl-auto=update` creating the tables on public schema automatically.

Comment: and how are you creating the new schema. Provide more details by code or create some reproducible example and put it to github or elsewhere. I also see that you've added liquibase tag. So are you using liquibase or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider#generateSchema(java.lang.String, java.util.Map)` and pass the name of the desired schema name through the map argument with the key `hibernate.default_schema`, but I wouldn't recommend using hbm2ddl for schema management. Rather use a tool like Liquibase or Flyway where you can be in full control of data migration to avoid data loss.